# Prevent incoming $_GET requests

Tags: rss, spam

I used to have an old RSS feed setup on one of my sites, but have since removed it - due to the number of users accessing it. For whatever reason the number of hits to the RSS feed has brought down my site - by spiking my CPU usage to well over 100%.

Now my site is un-reachable so I've hone ahead and removed the old RSS feed. Now I'm getting about 20-25 GET requests to the URL every 5 seconds, which now return a 404.

TLDR; Site was taken down by users hitting an RSS feed, RSS feed no longer exists - but users are still hitting the RSS feed, can't access my site due to a 504 Time-Out. Not sure how to best proceed - other than blocking incoming GET requests.

Thanks

Comment: Usually you could prevent this on .htaccess file, but why it is consuming your CPU? is that a WordPress 404 page where WP is loaded? if so then makes sense. You could `exit` (on `init`) all requests from there if you don't edit your .htaccess file. Also share with us a sample of the RSS feed URL

Comment: I wish I could tell you - been battling this for 2 days now with no clear end in site. I can't seem to locate the cause. Running on Digital Ocean, so not getting any support from them - I'm on my own. The RSS feed is gone, and no longer present on the site so there is nothing to share really. The feed was at www.example.com/?feed=adverts

Comment: That's bad. I was talking about something like `add_action("init", function() { if( isset( $_GET["feed"] ) && "adverts" == $_GET["feed"] ) { exit; } });` but since your site is gone and the bots are still requesting that RSS, you should block/deny them until you get access back to your site e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903448/htaccess-deny-specific-get-parameter

Comment: best to do this in `.htaccess` but until you get that right you could do what @SamuelEth is suggesting - but earlier (temporarily)... open wp-load.php and add `if ( (isset($_GET['feed']) && ($_GET['feed'] == 'adverts') ) {exit;}` as this will bypass WP load completely... of course it is dirty but it's fast and gives you time to find and implement a working `.htaccess` rule.